# Connect a web-app to to the back-end message queue

Tags: web-development, web-services, message-queue, front-end, backend

We are currently looking into dividing our back-end in multiple services using a message queue (RabbitMQ). Having a message queue suddenly gives us the possibility to update the web-app freely, but do we need to/want to use the message queue itself for that?

The web-client doesn't really send messages, but just regular web request that result in messages on the back-end. But now that we have detached some processes from web requests, we somehow have to notify the end user of the process of these tasks. (A task can take less then a second to more than a day).

Is it good practice to consume the messages on the front-end and setting up websockets etc to maintain the connection. Or would you solve a problem like this with regular polling of the back end in a specific interval based on expected duration? Do we actually need to notify the user is also something we are wondering (software design question really).

Some technologies we are using are Vuex(front-end), Django(backend API), RabbitMQ(message queue) and Heroku to deploy everything.